# Stackoverflow kind of Answer/commenting app in Django

Tags: django, comments

I was wondering if there is a pluggable application in Django that I can use which is a replica of Stackoverflow kind Answer and commenting.

Each post on my web app will have answers and all answers can have comments discussing that answer, just like SO.

Does anyone know such an app or has anyone been able to modify the Django commenting app to build this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### http://www.osqa.net/

Is written with django.

Comment: That's a full system. I have my own system which needs this extra feature of 'comments' (answers in SO terms) and 'discussion on comments' (comments in SO terms).

Comment: Hey @sabertooth did you ever find a solution? I'm looking for something too.

Comment: @FilipeFerminiano None yet. Although I found that Disqus was close if enough to what I could do with bare-minimum.